# Trying to Add a Specific Menu Depending on User Group

Tags: user-groups

I'm trying to show a menu based on what group a user is in once they have logged in.  However, I'm not having any success.  Here is an example (for one of the groups) of what I have in my `_base.html` file, which I'm extending in my other pages:

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('advisors') %}
    <div class="secondary-navigation">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-1 columns group">
                <h2>Advisors</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="small-11 columns navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Advisors Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Nav 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: That looks reasonable to me. What is it doing wrong?

Comment: It's not displaying the menu when I log in as a "client" user (or one of the others that I've got set up.

Comment: So you log in as a client, which is in the `advisors` group, but that piece of the nav doesn't get displayed? Do you have `devMode` on?

Comment: No.  I'm a Craft noob, and wasn't aware of that.  I will enable it and do some more testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so enabling the devMode helped point me in the right direction.

First, I needed to change it to

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.isInGroup('advisors') %}
```

Otherwise I was getting an error message when nobody was logged in ("Impossible to invoke a method ("isInGroup") on a null variable").

Then I discovered that the user I was testing wasn't added to any groups!  I could have sworn I set up the user with a group assigned, but apparently not.  :(